Nexti18 problema con enrutado
Configure mi proyecto de Next JS con nexti18 para traducir todo pero noto que en el enrutado solo me funciona con el locale en 'es' y en 'en' me da un not found, no se que pueda ser, mi configuración es esta, tal vez hice algo mal.

next.config.js :



const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config')

module.exports = {
  i18n,
}


next-i18next.config.js



module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'es'],
    defaultLocale: 'es',
  },
}


page.js



'use client';

import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import { appWithTranslation } from 'next-i18next'
import styles from './page.module.css';
import Dashboard from './dashboard/dashboard';

function Home() {

    
    return (
        <main className={`${styles.main}`}>
            <Dashboard />
            <ToastContainer position='top-center' />
        </main>
    );
}

export default appWithTranslation(Home);

no se que pueda ser, o si necesito una configuracion adicional
